# How to I change the button into hypertext in RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Here is the code for generate button, but I want it in a hyper text, how to modify this?

```
<% form_remote_tag (:url => { :action => :choose_category, :id => category }) do %>
  <%= submit_tag  category.name %>
<% end %>
```

I tried to use the `link_to`, but it can't submit a post method, what can I do?

Comment: `link_to` can do POST, use `:method => :post`.  It uses javascript to accomplish it.   It won't replicate the remote nature of the post though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want *replace* the submit button in your posted code with a regular hyperlink (`<a>` tag). Check out [link_to_remote](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001645). To understand the javascript code that generates, you may also want to check out the docs for Prototype's [Ajax.Updater](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater).

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks do not have the ability to submit POSTs (not in any browser that I know of, at least).  Forms are usually the best way to POST some data.

What you can do, however, is create a form on your page (with the appropriate methods and fields), then create a hyperlink with an `onclick` handler that will submit the form.  I'm not familiar with RoR to give you an example, but it should be a trivial change to the standard hyperlink-generating function.

(Note that the onclick handler should return `false` to prevent the link itself being followed; and ideally the `href` of the hyperlink would go to some acceptable page if people have Javascript disabled.)

Answer (score 0):

Links can't technically submit forms. That means you're limited to javascript, check out [`link_to_function`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#M001756). You'll need the `id` of the form you want to submit and then you can write some javascript like:

```
$('the_forms_id').submit(); return false;
```